# jQuery: dialog question - change button after init

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog

i've defined a dialog with 2 buttons: ok + cancel.
what i want to do now is change the ok button's function after initialization, so i tried:

```
dlgPrompt.dialog({
    buttons: {
        'Ok': function() {
            myFunction();
            $(this).dialog('close');
        }
    }
});
```

unfortunately it doesnt work (when clicking ok, nothing happens).
anyone knows whats wrong?

thx

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You need to call the `'option'` method, like this:

```
dlgPrompt.dialog('option', 'buttons', {
    'Ok': function() {
        myFunction();
        $(this).dialog('close');
    }
});
```

Comment: Still works with 3.2.1...and the preferred method of modifying the dialog buttons after init

Answer (score 4):

```
dlgPrompt.parent().find(".ui-dialog-buttonset .ui-button-text:eq(0)").text("FirstButton");
dlgPrompt.parent().find(".ui-dialog-buttonset .ui-button-text:eq(1)").text("SecondButton");
```

etc..

Comment: long way around but doable....i would definitely not suggest anyone do this, unless they had consumed all other alternatives.